# I need better solution to get time of execution program in C

Tags: c, time

I am using this

```
 clock_t start = clock();

    QuickSort(0, ItemCount-1,1);

 printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

I would like to get time in nanoseconds.

Comment: And use the search function. This is asked pretty much every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Unix-like system you can most likely use the `clock_gettime()` function. In Linux, it is found in `-lrt`, most other systems I've tried have it in the system C library.

It should be noted that x86 has an `rdtsc` instruction that is extremely precise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `struct timespec` as follows to obtain the time of execution of the code in nanoseconds precision

```
struct timespec start, end;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
/* Do something */
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&end);
```

It returns a value as `((((unsigned64)start.tv_sec) * ((unsigned64)(1000000000L))) + ((unsigned64)(start.tv_nsec))))`

Hope this answer will be more helpful for you to get your desired execution time in nanoseconds.